# How pack dir to msi file

Tags: windows-installer

I use msiexec to unpack msi file and replace *.dll.

```
msiexec /a Ica32Pkg.msi /qb
```

but i dont understand how backward pack dir to msi

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a tool named  xml2msi.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/msi2xml/

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MSI2XMLAndBackconvertingWindowsInstallerDatabasesToXML.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed InstallShield and the problem was solved. Thanks.